# SQL Select statement issue, how to solve

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables. They are called `BB_CONTACT` and `BB_PHONE`.

- `BB_CONTACT` has `name` (primary key) and `phone`.
- `BB_PHONE` has `name`, `phone` and `replacement` (true or false)

I need to make a query that lists only `BB_CONTACT` people that need their phones replaced.

```
SELECT 
    BB_CONTACT.CONTACTNAME, 
from 
    BB_CONTACT, BB_PHONE
WHERE
    BB_PHONE.CONTACTNAME = BB_CONTACT.CONTACTNAME
```

The query above shows contacts that are in both `BB_CONTACT` and `BB_PHONE` tables. However, I need to make a SQL select statement that checks the person in `BB_CONTACT` is one of the following:

- BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = 'TRUE' AND BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NOT NULL OR
- BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = 'TRUE' AND BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NULL OR
- BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = 'FALSE' AND BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NULL;

I do not want to include people who match the following:

```
BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = false AND BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NOT NULL;
```

Sorry if this appears simple, I have been stuck. I am using JDBC.

Comment: `(` and `)` are your friend.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: You can simplify your logic to:  `BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = 'TRUE' OR BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe this is what you are after:

```
SELECT C.CONTACTNAME
FROM BB_CONTACT AS C
  JOIN BB_PHONE AS P 
  ON C.CONTACTNAME = P.CONTACTNAME
WHERE 
  (
    P.REPLACEMENT = 'TRUE' OR
    (P.REPLACEMENT = 'FALSE' AND C.PHONENUMBER IS NULL)
  )
```

I simplified the WHERE condition.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there ... try this:

```
SELECT BB_CONTACT.CONTACTNAME, 
from BB_CONTACT JOIN BB_PHONE ON BB_PHONE.CONTACTNAME = BB_CONTACT.CONTACTNAME
WHERE 
(
  (BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = 'TRUE' AND BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NOT NULL) OR
  (BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = 'TRUE' AND BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NULL) OR
  (BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = 'FALSE' AND BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NULL)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You answered the question yourself, just put the statement together and the result will be something like this

```
SELECT BB_CONTACT.CONTACTNAME, 
FROM BB_CONTACT
INNER JOIN BB_PHONE ON BB_PHONE.CONTACTNAME = BB_CONTACT.CONTACTNAME
WHERE
(
  BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = 'TRUE' AND BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NOT NULL OR
  BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = 'TRUE' AND BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NULL OR
  BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = 'FALSE' AND BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NULL
)
AND
(
  BB_PHONE.REPLACEMENT = 'FALSE' AND BB_CONTACT.PHONENUMBER IS NOT NULL
);
```

There are more elegant ways to resolve your problem but that should do it.

Comment: *@fossilcoder*, the way you have your WHERE clause, your query will not return any records.